# Use of OpenSSL BN_hex2bn in Swift 4 - How to build the handle

Tags: swift, openssl, swift4.2

I have to use the `int BN_hex2bn(BIGNUM **a, const char *str);` into a Swift class; I've actually prepared following code:

```
class Test {
    var N : UnsafeMutablePointer<BIGNUM>
    var N_hex: String = "...HEX VALUE...";
    init() {
        self.N = BN_new()
    }
    use() {
        var Nhandle: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<BIGNUM>?>? = [???]
        BN_hex2bn(Nhandle, self.N_hex);
    }
}
```

Well, as you can understand I have some issue to initialize the handle! :-)

Better: It's the right way to use such function in Swift? Is there a different approach? How can I initialize the handle?

Thank you for answers!

Comment: Obviously `var N_hex: String = "...HEX VALUE..."` is not a ASCII encoded hex string and `BN_hex2bn` should fail.

Comment: @jww - Do yo have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BN_hex2bn()` expects the address of a `BIGNUM *` as the first argument, in Swift that is the address of an `UnsafeMutablePointer<BIGNUM>?` variable. You “only” have to declare that variable (optionals are automatically initialized with `nil`) and pass it as an inout-argument with `&` to the function. Example:

```
let hexString = "123456789abcdef"

var bn: UnsafeMutablePointer<BIGNUM>?
BN_hex2bn(&bn, hexString)

// Do something with `bn` ...   

// Eventually free the memory:
BN_free(bn)
```

If you wrap it in a Swift class then releasing the resources can be done in the `deinit` method:

```
class BN {
    var bn: UnsafeMutablePointer<BIGNUM>?

    init(hexString: String) {
        BN_hex2bn(&bn, hexString)
    }

    deinit {
        if let bn = bn { BN_free(bn) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the result: "Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: implicit conversion from 'UnsafeMutablePointer<BIGNUM>' to 'UnsafeMutablePointer<BIGNUM>?' requires a temporary"
As old C programmer the "&" solution seems to me the right solution but... ;-) Moreover as someone stated above the Swift String type is a unicode string, not an ASCII string; this may cause issue? I have to convert unicode string to ASCII string? (How?)

Comment: @FrancescoPiraneoG.: I tested my suggested code, it compiles and works as expected. Did you declare the variable as `UnsafeMutablePointer<BIGNUM>?`  (with the question mark at the end)? – Swift strings can be passed directly to C functions, the compiler creates a temporary C string representation.

Comment: Question mark missing... sorry! Now it works! :-) Thank you very much!